# How to create a list of length x with identical elements?

Tags: kdb

I would like to create a list in q/kdb of variable length `x` which contains the same element `e` repeated. For example:

```
x:4;
e:`this;
expected_result:`this`this`this`this
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take is what you're looking for:
https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/take/

```
q)x:4
q)e:`this
q)x#e
`this`this`this`this
```

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by all, `#` is the best solution in the singular case. If you wanted to duplicate multiple items into a larger single list, then `where` can achieve this nicely

```
q)`this`that where 4 2
`this`this`this`this`that`that
```

Comment: For some diversity - ``(`this`this)  1 1 1 1``

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `#` https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/take/

```
q)n:4
q)vals:`this
q)n#vals
`this`this`this`this
```

Answer (score 2):

Use ['#'(take)](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/take/) function:

```
 q) x:4
 q) e:`this
 q) x#e
```